# pgfplots: markers with text above the marked points

Tags: pgfplots

first an image of what I would like to have

[image: that' they way I want it]

I want to have a free text of the nth marker of each plot. I am symply providing no example, because I am not really sure to solve it and I am maybe searching in the wrong direction.

boundary condition: I am using matlab2tikz and therefore the plots contain MANY points. Specifying a specific point for each plot manually would take hours. I would prefere something like for markers

text mark={text},
mark phase=5,
mark repeat=300,

but there the text would be placed on the point and a vertical shift would be missing.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you provide the basis plot that you have drawn the markers with? We can take it from there to try out solutions.

Answer (score 2):

ok, found out a solution. I think there is a better one, so I am looking forward to other suggestions. The last think what would be desirable is an additional verical shift of the markers.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=4.52083333333333in,
height=3.565625in,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=4,
xtick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
ymin=0,
ymax=4,
ytick={0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
]
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
%mark=*,
mark phase=2,
mark repeat=6,
nodes near coords={(text1)},
every node near coord/.style={text=black, anchor=south west},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 2\\
1 3\\
2 3\\
3 2\\
4 1\\
};
\addplot [
color=green!50!black,
solid,
%mark=square*,
mark phase=2,
mark repeat=6,
nodes near coords={(text2)},
every node near coord/.style={text=black, anchor=south west},
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
0 1\\
1 1\\
2 1\\
3 1\\
4 1\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: You can shift the text up by adding `yshift=1cm` to the `every node near coord/.style`. This looks like a good solution, why do you think there might be a better one?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pgf-plots, but you can always add text atop of the image after the fact:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\bottominset{Free Text}{%
  \bottominset{\parbox{1in}{Free\\Text}}{%
    \includegraphics{tkoWu}%
  }{100pt}{75pt}%
}{150pt}{175pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]